# XHR Post request is giving 412

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have an XHR POST request URL for a specific website but I am not able to understand how to use the query parameters. I am trying it out using Python 3.11 using the requests library but I am getting 412 every time. However, 412 says that some predefined conditions in request headers are not met and I am not sure what headers I need to add.
the request URL I am trying to POST the request to is [this is the URL](https://www.ems.com.cn/) and when you enter the value `LV753481665CN` and submit, in the networks tab the XHR request [this URL would be visible](https://www.ems.com.cn/ems-web/cutPic/getPic). Now if you see the headers and query param attached to the URL it seems a value and it keeps on changing with every request. So, my goal is to get that response from that URL. Currently, I am getting 412. while sending the request without query param.

you can see the query parameters and it keeps on changing with each request. The headers I am trying out are

```
    self.session.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    self.session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    self.session.headers['Origin'] = 'https://www.ems.com.cn'
    self.session.headers['Host'] = 'www.ems.com.cn'
    self.session.headers['Referer'] = 'https://www.ems.com.cn'
```

I am using MacOS. Please let me know how can I resolve it. Please help. Earlier it was working and now it says 412. I am using `r = self.session.post('https://www.ems.com.cn/ems-web/cutPic/getPic')` to post and not passing any payload or query params.

Comment: Looks like they are encoding or encrypting the value somehow, before the request is made. So you'd have to go and find the JavaScript part that does that.

Comment: Thanks for responding @CBroe. I tried the same using Postman but was not able to get the output either. Can you please tell me if I can get the output in the postman I am sure I should be able to.

Comment: It did not work for me, I was not able to find the script where it was encoding and sending a query parameter, I tried looking for and I found the piece of script where it sends the post request but I did not find any data attached to it, here is the code that I found please help If you can @CBroe

Comment: `                getImageVerifyCode: function() {
                    var t = this;
                    this.$axios.post("/cutPic/getPic").then((function(e) {
                        t.capcodeData = e.value.capcode,
                        t.$nextTick((function() {
                            t.$refs.dialogopen && t.$refs.dialogopen.reset(t.catcha.blocky)
                        }
                        )),
                        t.showSlide = !0
                    }
                    )).catch((function(t) {}
                    ))
                },`
@CBroe

Comment: Don't see how _that_ could cause a request to `https://www.ems.com.cn/ems-web/cutPic/getPic?uB04BPdr=...` First of all, `/cutPic/getPic` should result in `https://www.ems.com.cn/cutPic/getPic` - unclear how the `ems-web` folder at the beginning of the path would get into this. And the parameter name `uB04BPdr` is not in that code at all.

Comment: When i inspected more I found out that it is doing of axios but I am not sure how, I used the debugger that chrome browser provides. I checked for the uB04BPdr in the XHR url and I found out that axios is doing this but, I am not familiar with it so I couldn’t dig more. I was able to capture the URL before it actually sends the request but I was unable to understand how that query parameter is being formed but I am sure it was doing of axios.

Comment: Could perhaps be via an interceptor, https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Comment: Okay, I read about and it actually transforms the request by adding access token to it. But in this case it is being changed for every request and with every refresh. So, I want to know if we can get or generate this token in any way via python, so that I can mimic it to bypass the 412 or any other 4xx issue. Is there any way, please let me know.